# TFS2013 Git multi-project automated build web.config transform not working

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, web.config-transform

I can't get MS Build to output a transformed `Web.Config` file. I've setup the build project using NuGet package restore as described in the [NuGet docs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/27/nuget-package-restore-with-team-foundation-build.aspx). Every part of the build works (package restore, CI, web deploy packages) except for the transform. I have tried the base setup and a [custom project file](http://blog.degree.no/2012/03/automatic-config-transformations/) as well as lot of other options and I haven't gotten anywhere.

I've done config transform setups before without issue. I have Slow Cheetah installed and can preview my current transform and see that it works. When I run the build locally via `MSBuild.exe`, the transform actually happens:

```
    TransformWebConfigCore:
  Transforming Source File: G:\MyProject\Web.config
    Applying Transform File: G:\MyProject\Web.Debug.config
    Output File: obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config
  Transformation succeeded
```

(If I look at the -v output I can see the individual transform run)

Then Web Deploy parameterizes my `web.config`:

```
Transformed Web.config using G:\MyProject\Web.Debug.config into obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
PipelineTransformPhase:
  Publish Pipeline Transform Phase
PreAutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings:
  Creating directory "G:\MyProject\obj\Debug\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Views\".
  Copying obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config to obj\Debug\CSAutoParameterize\original\Web.config.
AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStringsCore:
  Transforming Source File: G:\MyProject\Views\Web.config
    Applying Transform File: <?xml version="1.0"?>
          <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
            <connectionStrings>
              <add
                connectionString="{% token='$(ReplacableToken_#(parameter)_#(tokennumber))' xpathlocator='name' parameter='$(name)-Web.config Connection String' description='$(name) Connection String used in web.config by the application to access the database.' defaultValue='$(connectionString)' tags='SqlConnectionString' %}"
                xdt:Transform="SetTokenizedAttributes(connectionString)" xdt:SupressWarnings="True" />
            </connectionStrings>
          </configuration>
    No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings'
    Not executing SetTokenizedAttributes (transform line 6, 15)
    Output File: obj\Debug\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Views\Web.config
  Transformation succeeded
PostAutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings:
  Auto ConnectionString Transformed obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config into obj\Debug\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config.
```

The parameterized file is then moved into the package and the transformed file is deleted.

Copying obj\Debug\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config.
  Deleting file "obj\Debug\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config".

So I have a transformed `web.config` file that doesn't end up in my build output. Why does the transform happen but not get copied to the output directory or the web deploy package?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here. This is caused by the Web Deploy Pattern. It uses the `"project name".SetParameters.xml` in the `Web_Package` to replace values on Deploy.

Since you want to use `SlowCheetah` you need to circumvent this.

You can accomplish this by replacing the connectionstrings setting in your web.config by:

```
    <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config">
    </connectionStrings>
```

Of course you will need the connectionStrings.config file. You van create this manually and put in the originasl connectionStrings section.
The  node should be the only node in the file.

Now you can add `SlowCheetah` Transform on your `connectionStrings.config` file.